# WPF throws System.NullReferenceException when trying to modify xaml elements

Tags: c#, wpf

Ive been trying to make a Germany excersice program (trying to learn it but its hard) but I ran into "System.NullReferenceException" error. Any idea what is causing that AND how to fix it ? Thanks :)

I have been looking for a way to change multiple (up to 20 in this case) objects parameter to a certain value with not HUUUGE code and crazy ways about it because I am pretty new programmer and still dont know all the shortcuts and stuff :D

I browsed alot on the internet trying to find a way to do it but I was not succesfull so I am asking here. Sorry if its alot of code I think its better to post all then miss something that doesnt seem important to me but actually is important right ? :)

Oh and I encountered the exception in the "((("clen" + x) as object) as TextBox).IsEnabled = true;" part. But it think it would also happen at any other place in the code where i am using similiar as-as part

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="NJ.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NJ"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="900" Width="1600">
<Grid>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="10,59,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" Name="clen1" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="106,59,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="39" Width="427" Name="slovicko1" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="10,110,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" x:Name="clen2" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="106,110,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="39" Width="427" x:Name="slovicko2" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="10,161,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" x:Name="clen3" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="106,161,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="39" Width="427" x:Name="slovicko3" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="10,212,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" x:Name="clen4" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="106,212,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="427" x:Name="slovicko4" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="10,264,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" x:Name="clen5" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="106,264,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="39" Width="427" x:Name="slovicko5" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="10,315,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" x:Name="clen6" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="106,315,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="39" Width="427" x:Name="slovicko6" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="10,366,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" x:Name="clen7" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="106,366,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="39" Width="427" x:Name="slovicko7" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="10,417,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" x:Name="clen8" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="106,417,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="427" x:Name="slovicko8" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="10,468,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" x:Name="clen9" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="106,468,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="427" x:Name="slovicko9" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="10,520,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" x:Name="clen10" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="106,520,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="39" Width="427" x:Name="slovicko10" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="651,59,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" x:Name="clen11" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="746,59,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="39" Width="428" x:Name="slovicko11" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="651,110,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" x:Name="clen12" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="746,110,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="39" Width="428" x:Name="slovicko12" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="651,161,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" x:Name="clen13" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="746,161,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="39" Width="428" x:Name="slovicko13" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="651,212,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" x:Name="clen14" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="746,212,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="428" x:Name="slovicko14" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="651,264,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" x:Name="clen15" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="746,264,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="39" Width="428" x:Name="slovicko15" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="651,315,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" x:Name="clen16" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="746,315,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="39" Width="428" x:Name="slovicko16" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="651,366,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" x:Name="clen17" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="746,366,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="39" Width="428" x:Name="slovicko17" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="651,417,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" x:Name="clen18" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="746,417,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="428" x:Name="slovicko18" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="651,468,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" x:Name="clen19" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="746,468,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="428" x:Name="slovicko19" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="651,520,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" x:Name="clen20" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="746,520,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="39" Width="428" x:Name="slovicko20" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1266,33,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Od lekce:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="39" Width="90" FontSize="20"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="1362,31,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="38" Name="zacateklekci" FontSize="25"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1426,33,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="do lekce:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="39" Width="90" FontSize="20"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="1520,31,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="38" Name="koneclekci" FontSize="25"/>
    <Slider HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1290,110,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Maximum="20" Height="39" Width="250" TickPlacement="BottomRight" TickFrequency="1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Name="wordcount" Minimum="1" Value="1"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1236,109,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ElementName=wordcount, Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="49" FontSize="25"/>
    <Button Content="Nový test" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1266,161,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="274" Height="39" FontSize="25" Click="Button_Click" Name="generateTest"/>
    <Button Content="Zkontrolovat" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1266,264,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="274" Height="39" FontSize="25" Click="kontroluj" Name="zkontolujbutton"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1266,315,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="39" Width="274" FontSize="25" Name="pocetchyb"/>

</Grid>
```

C# backcode

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public int chyby = 0;
    public List<string> comparelist = new List<string>();
    public List<string> derlist = new List<string>();
    public List<string> dielist = new List<string>();
    public List<string> daslist = new List<string>();
    public List<string> blacklist = new List<string>();
    int tmp1 = 1;
    int tmp2 = 1;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Int32.TryParse(zacateklekci.Text, out tmp1) && Int32.TryParse(koneclekci.Text, out tmp2))
        {
            if (tmp1 < 8 && tmp1 > 0 && tmp2 < 8 && tmp2 > 0)
            {
                chyby = 0;
                for (int i = 1; i <= tmp2; i++)
                {
                    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Honza\Documents\VS Files\nj\data" + i + "der.json"))
                    {
                        string json = r.ReadToEnd();
                        foreach (string s in JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<String>>(json)) derlist.Add(s);
                    }
                    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Honza\Documents\VS Files\nj\data" + i + "die.json"))
                    {
                        string json = r.ReadToEnd();
                        foreach (string s in JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<String>>(json)) dielist.Add(s);
                    }
                    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Honza\Documents\VS Files\nj\data" + i + "das.json"))
                    {
                        string json = r.ReadToEnd();
                        foreach (string s in JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<String>>(json)) daslist.Add(s);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int x = 1; x <= (wordcount.Value + 1); x++)
        {
            ((("clen" + x) as object) as TextBox).IsEnabled = true;
            ((("slovicko" + x) as object) as TextBlock).IsEnabled = true;
            int tmp = 0;
            switch (rand.Next(3))
            {
                case 1:
                    comparelist.Add("die");
                    do
                    {
                        tmp = rand.Next((dielist.Count + 1));
                    } while (blacklist.Contains(dielist[tmp]));
                    ((("slovicko" + x) as object) as TextBlock).Text = dielist[tmp];
                    blacklist.Add(dielist[tmp]);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    comparelist.Add("das");
                    do
                    {
                        tmp = rand.Next((daslist.Count + 1));
                    } while (blacklist.Contains(daslist[tmp]));
                    ((("slovicko" + x) as object) as TextBlock).Text = daslist[tmp];
                    blacklist.Add(daslist[tmp]);
                    break;
                default:
                    comparelist.Add("der");
                    do
                    {
                        tmp = rand.Next((derlist.Count + 1));
                    } while (blacklist.Contains(derlist[tmp]));
                    ((("slovicko" + x) as object) as TextBlock).Text = derlist[tmp];
                    blacklist.Add(derlist[tmp]);
                    break;
            }
        }
        generateTest.IsEnabled = false;
        zkontolujbutton.IsEnabled = true;
    }

    public void ClearComparsion()
    {
        comparelist = new List<string>();
        derlist = new List<string>();
        dielist = new List<string>();
        daslist = new List<string>();
        blacklist = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++)
            {
                ((("clen" + i) as object) as TextBox).IsEnabled = false;
                ((("clen" + i) as object) as TextBox).Background = Brushes.Transparent;
                ((("clen" + i) as object) as TextBox).Text = null;
                ((("slovicko" + i) as object) as TextBlock).IsEnabled = false;
                ((("slovicko" + i) as object) as TextBlock).Background = Brushes.Transparent;
                ((("slovicko" + i) as object) as TextBlock).Text = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        generateTest.IsEnabled = true;
        zkontolujbutton.IsEnabled = false;
    }

    private void kontroluj(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= (wordcount.Value + 1); i++)
        {
            if (((("clen" + i) as object) as TextBox).Text.ToLower().Equals(comparelist[i]))
            {
                ((("clen" + i) as object) as TextBox).Background = Brushes.LightGreen;
            } else
            {
                ((("clen" + i) as object) as TextBox).Background = Brushes.Pink;
                chyby++;
            }
        }
        ClearComparsion();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where you have the `System.NullReferenceException`?

Comment: ((("clen" + x) as object) as TextBox).IsEnabled = true; Havent got any further in executing it cuz this method HAS to be ran at least once at start

Comment: Oh and I dont mind using some... "Sketchier" element manipulation or other things because its program only for my own use :)

Comment: `((("clen" + x) as object) as TextBox).IsEnabled = true;` - please explain what you think this will accomplish, because I don't believe it does what you think it does.

Comment: I named my textboxes clen1 to 20 so I could use some kind of looping function to go over them 1 by 1 and change their attributes. And I thought whe clen1.IsEnabled works then this should work too because it like points at the same object no ?

Comment: Okay, but `as` simply means `treat what's on the left as a type of what's on the right` - it does not look up an actual existing instance of anything.

Comment: So is there any way to do what I am trying to do ? I would really appreciate if I didnt have to write the changes one by one :/ And is there any way to point to an actual object similiar to what I am doing with the incresing number ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your logic to find/access controls, for example `((("clen" + x) as object) as TextBox)` and similar code where you cast object as a `TextBox`.

when you say `("clen" + x) as object` is essentially a `String` object and not a `TextBox` object. So when you cast the `String` object to `TextBox`, it will result in a null.

To fix the issue, you can use [`FindName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.FrameworkElement.FindName);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2) method which will search for all elements for a given name on the window. Mind that you cannot use it to search for elements in side templates, which you are not doing. So the fixed code will look like:

```
(FindName("clen" + x) as TextBox)
```

Make sure to check for null result.

Comment: Can I just ask what do u mean by "make sure to check for null?" Thanks :)

Comment: Just a check: var tb = FindName("clen" + x) as TextBox; if(tb != null) // safe to proceed